# I want to create category with our custom id using rest api is it possible?

Tags: magento2

```
$data = array(
    'category' => 
        array (
            'id'=>45,
            'parent_id'=>1,
            'name' =>top,
            'is_active' => 1,
            'include_in_menu' => true
        )
    );
```

Comment: Id is the primary column, why you need to create that with category ID?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya issue is that I am getting these category id and name both from API, so if I want to add product on behalf of category id also, then if I use auto increment category then the product which will come from API will be different in that category. ?

Comment: I am working on last one week but not getting any solution